# swift tableview change reloadData to insertRows

Tags: swift, uitableview

trying to change method to update the data, because with reloadData have lag

```
let oldIns = insertCounter
insertCounter += Int(INSERT_MESSAGES) // +40
var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
for section in (oldIns..<insertCounter) {
    indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: 2, section: section))
}
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

but i have error

> The number of sections contained in the table view after the update
>   (80) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table
>   view before the update (40), plus or minus the number of sections
>   inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted)

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return min(insertCounter, Int(dbmessages.count))
}

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 5
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return RCMessages().sectionHeaderMargin
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return RCMessages().sectionFooterMargin
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

        view.tintColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

        view.tintColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            return RCSectionHeaderCell.height(indexPath, messagesView: self)
        }

        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            return RCBubbleHeaderCell.height(indexPath, messagesView: self)
        }

        if (indexPath.row == 2) {

            let rcmessage = self.rcmessage(indexPath)
            if (rcmessage.type == RC_TYPE_STATUS)   { return RCStatusCell.height(indexPath, messagesView: self)             }
            if (rcmessage.type == RC_TYPE_TEXT)     { return RCTextMessageCell.height(indexPath, messagesView: self)        }

        }

        if (indexPath.row == 3) {
            return RCBubbleFooterCell.height(indexPath, messagesView: self)
        }

        if (indexPath.row == 4) {
            return RCSectionFooterCell.height(indexPath, messagesView: self)
        }
        return 0
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RCSectionHeaderCell", for: indexPath) as! RCSectionHeaderCell
            cell.bindData(indexPath, messagesView: self)
            return cell
        }

        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RCBubbleHeaderCell", for: indexPath) as! RCBubbleHeaderCell
            cell.bindData(indexPath, messagesView: self)
            return cell
        }

        if (indexPath.row == 2) {

            let rcmessage = self.rcmessage(indexPath)
            if (rcmessage.type == RC_TYPE_STATUS) {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RCStatusCell", for: indexPath) as! RCStatusCell
                cell.bindData(indexPath, messagesView: self)
                return cell
            }

            if (rcmessage.type == RC_TYPE_TEXT) {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RCTextMessageCell", for: indexPath) as! RCTextMessageCell
                cell.bindData(indexPath, messagesView: self)

                let numSections = self.tableView.numberOfSections
                if numSections == 1  {
                    updateTableContentInset()
                }
                return cell
            }

        }

        if (indexPath.row == 3) {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RCBubbleFooterCell", for: indexPath) as! RCBubbleFooterCell
            cell.bindData(indexPath, messagesView: self)
            return cell
        }

        if (indexPath.row == 4) {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RCSectionFooterCell", for: indexPath) as! RCSectionFooterCell
            cell.bindData(indexPath, messagesView: self)
            return cell
        }

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

How can i correct insert new row in `tableview`? 
Before does like this

```
insertCounter += Int(INSERT_MESSAGES)
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: return min(insertCounter, Int(dbmessages.count))

can you explain that?

Comment: @Manish_Nainwal i load to tableview part of database (few message). when i scroll up i want to add another part of database, insertCounter - is count how much messages i wont to add in to tableview

Comment: I realized that I need to add a row but the section can u help me how to add a new section ?

Comment: you have to return the total  count after updating debug and chek the number of section before and after the update.

Comment: same as insertRow theres a method insertSection

Comment: @Manish_Nainwal add `tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(indexesIn: NSMakeRange(oldIns, insertCounter-1)) as IndexSet, with: .automatic) ` but have error `attempt to insert section 80 but there are only 80 sections after the update`

Comment: check after inserting section have you update the numberOfSection too or not?

Comment: @Manish_Nainwal if i write range like this `tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(indexesIn: NSMakeRange(0, 80)) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)` then have error `invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (80) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (40), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (80 inserted, 0 deleted).`

Comment: yes because you are not updating the numberOfSection

Comment: @Manish_Nainwal no. i paste breakpoint in numberOfSections and it return 80 (before he have 40)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403808/uitableview-multiple-insertsections-to-same-index

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty simple code line:

```
 tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .top)
```

This will insert the new row at the top of the table view. Then you would reload the data. This should fix the problem.